# Python C++ Wrapper API

Tags: python, c++

Short question: Are anyone aware of a C++ API for Python (A C++ wrapper for the Python C API)

Long question:

I have used the following for wrapping C/C++ for Python usage:

- Manual wrapping using `PyMethodDef` and `Py_InitModule`
- SWIG
- Pyrex
- ctypes
- SIP
- Boost.Python
- pybind11

They are all very good for wrapping C/C++ for Python usage, but loading modules, creating python objects and calling python methods from C/C++ requires a lot of boilerplate like shown below

```
std::string module = "mymodule";
std::string function = "myfun";
float seven = 7.0f;

PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pFunc, *pArgs, *pValue;

pName = PyString_FromStringAndSize(module.c_str(), module.size());
pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
Py_DECREF(pName);
if (pModule != NULL) {
  pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, function.c_str());
  if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {
    int argc = 4;
    pArgs = PyTuple_New(argc - 3);
    for (int i = 0; i < argc - 3; ++i) {
      pValue =  PyFloat_FromDouble(static_cast<double>(seven));
      if (!pValue) {
        Py_DECREF(pArgs);
        Py_DECREF(pModule);
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot convert argument\n");
        return 1;
      }
      /* pValue reference stolen here: */
      PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, i, pValue);
    }
    pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
    Py_DECREF(pArgs);
    if (pValue != NULL) {
      printf("Result of call: %ld\n", PyLong_AsLong(pValue));
      Py_DECREF(pValue);
    }  else {
      Py_DECREF(pFunc);
      Py_DECREF(pModule);
      PyErr_Print();
      fprintf(stderr, "Call failed\n");
      return 1;
    }
  } else {
    if (PyErr_Occurred())
      PyErr_Print();
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find function \"%s\"\n", function.c_str());
  }
  Py_XDECREF(pFunc);
  Py_DECREF(pModule);
} else {
    PyErr_Print();
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load \"%s\"\n", module.c_str());
    return 1;
}
return 0;
```

Is there any C++ wrapper available for the Python C API???

I am thinking that the above could be executed like

```
try {
    const EmbeddedPython& ep = EmbeddedPython::InstanceGet();
    ep.PathPrepend(".");
    ep.Module("mymodule").Function("myfunction", 7.0f);
}
catch(...) {
}
```

where a singleton would ensure to call `Py_Initialize` and `Py_Finalize`, keep track of modules loaded, handle exceptions, `Function` could be implemented using variadic templates and ensure proper conversion of all arguments. The default conversion could be to use runtime type information and a runtime for type conversion, e.g. SWIG or SIP.

Are anyone aware of a C++ API for Python?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try pybind11, the [embedding](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/embedding.html#importing-modules) part.

Comment: @n.m. It seems like the embedding part is step in the right direction, but for the application I am writing I am making use of sub-interpreters, which is not supported by `pybind11` - further thread-safety is an issue.